# How do I get all the rows of data for a specific month,or days; over a range of many years using pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am attempting to find seasonal trends in the stock market. I want to have the ability to see how an asset has preformed i.e. what is the average return for appl(apple computer) in the month of May, since 1990?  Also I would like to see i.e how has aapl performed between September and December since 1990. Finally I would also like the ability to see what days were the most profitable i.e. what was the average return for appl on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday since 1990?

I am using pandas dataframes and am loading my data from a csv file loaded from yahoo finance. No matter what try I can't get this to work right, any help or input would be greatly appreciated. Also I am not using apple's stock for my code but ticker CDE

In addition, when I run my code I get only the end and the beginning of my data, how do I get it to where it will display all 6000+ rows?

```
from pandas_datareader import data as dreader
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("cde_data.csv",index_col='Date')


print(df['1900-05':'2016-05'])
```

I am trying to get the return for the month of may but I get I range instead

```
              Open    High     Low   Close   Volume   Adj Close
Date
1990-04-12  26.875  26.875  26.625  26.625     6100  250.576036
1990-04-16  26.500  26.750  26.375  26.750      500  251.752449
1990-04-17  26.750  26.875  26.750  26.875     2300  252.928863
1990-04-18  26.875  26.875  26.500  26.625     3500  250.576036
1990-04-19  26.500  26.750  26.500  26.750      700  251.752449
1990-04-20  26.750  26.875  26.750  26.875     2100  252.928863
1990-04-23  26.875  26.875  26.750  26.875      700  252.928863
1990-04-24  27.000  27.000  26.000  26.000     2400  244.693970
1990-04-25  25.250  25.250  24.875  25.125     9300  236.459076
1990-04-26  25.000  25.250  24.750  25.000     1200  235.282663
1990-04-27  25.000  25.250  25.000  25.250     1100  237.635490
1990-04-30  25.125  25.250  25.000  25.125     3500  236.459076
1990-05-01  25.375  25.500  25.250  25.250     1100  237.635490
1990-05-02  25.125  25.125  24.000  24.250     1800  228.224183
1990-05-03  25.000  25.000  24.625  24.750     9100  232.929836
1990-05-04  24.625  24.875  24.375  24.750      500  232.929836
1990-05-07  25.000  25.000  24.625  24.625      900  231.753423
1990-05-08  24.875  25.250  24.875  25.125      400  236.459076
1990-05-09  25.375  25.875  25.250  25.875     6900  243.517556
1990-05-10  26.000  26.750  26.000  26.750     5500  251.752449
1990-05-11  27.000  27.000  26.875  27.000     1800  254.105276
1990-05-14  27.000  27.250  26.750  27.000     6800  254.105276
1990-05-15  27.000  27.125  26.625  26.750     3300  251.752449
1990-05-16  26.625  26.625  25.875  25.875     2600  243.517556
1990-05-17  26.125  26.500  26.000  26.375      500  248.223210
1990-05-18  26.250  26.875  26.250  26.875     1000  252.928863
1990-05-21  27.375  27.375  26.875  27.375     2700  257.634516
1990-05-22  27.625  28.250  27.500  27.875     2000  262.340169
1990-05-23  27.375  28.500  27.125  28.000     4000  263.516583
1990-05-24  28.250  28.375  27.625  27.875     1100  262.340169
...            ...     ...     ...     ...      ...         ...
2016-03-18   5.490   5.750   5.390   5.590  9415600    5.590000
2016-03-21   5.560   5.940   5.550   5.760  4018800    5.760000
2016-03-22   5.810   5.890   5.680   5.800  3429600    5.800000
2016-03-23   5.330   5.570   5.200   5.250  4445500    5.250000
2016-03-24   5.260   5.400   5.150   5.280  2668800    5.280000
2016-03-28   5.320   5.480   5.210   5.440  2093700    5.440000
2016-03-29   5.400   5.850   5.380   5.710  3709800    5.710000
2016-03-30   5.640   5.780   5.490   5.650  2444900    5.650000
2016-03-31   5.800   5.860   5.570   5.620  2319800    5.620000
2016-04-01   5.410   5.650   5.210   5.640  2922400    5.640000
2016-04-04   5.620   5.690   5.430   5.550  2561200    5.550000
2016-04-05   5.620   5.770   5.440   5.730  2294900    5.730000
2016-04-06   5.630   5.880   5.610   5.820  2108400    5.820000
2016-04-07   5.900   6.110   5.870   5.940  2963100    5.940000
2016-04-08   5.790   6.030   5.750   6.010  3583700    6.010000
2016-04-11   6.160   6.500   6.110   6.490  5140100    6.490000
2016-04-12   6.580   6.730   6.330   6.720  4015000    6.720000
2016-04-13   6.640   6.990   6.600   6.700  3972300    6.700000
2016-04-14   6.660   6.750   6.220   6.380  4125700    6.380000
2016-04-15   6.410   6.750   6.370   6.670  2907800    6.670000
2016-04-18   6.700   6.830   6.530   6.790  2452900    6.790000
2016-04-19   7.110   7.450   6.970   7.380  6057600    7.380000
2016-04-20   7.410   7.680   6.820   7.000  6494400    7.000000
2016-04-21   7.300   7.530   6.940   7.140  4394000    7.140000
2016-04-22   7.080   7.380   6.730   6.890  3838700    6.890000
2016-04-25   6.850   7.040   6.720   6.870  2905400    6.870000
2016-04-26   6.900   7.190   6.700   7.100  2743900    7.100000
2016-04-27   7.160   7.280   6.870   7.180  3558900    7.180000
2016-04-28   7.350   7.960   7.080   7.440  6516000    7.440000
2016-04-29   7.650   8.140   7.650   8.100  6457000    8.100000

[6564 rows x 6 columns]
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the standard libraries [**`datetime`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) and write helper functions to do the conversions you want.  Then make a new column by applying the helper function to the Date column.

```
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser

def hour(x):
    return(x.hour)
def dow(x):
    return(x.isoweekday())
def month(x):
    return(x.month)

df.reset_index()
df.Date     = df.Date.apply(dateutil.parser.parse)
df["hour"]  = df.Date.apply(hour)
df["dow"]   = df.Date.apply(dow)
df["month"] = df.Date.apply(month)
```

Now you can do group by on the column you have created or slice on the column you have created.  To get all the Fridays in January slice like this:

```
df[(df.dow == 5) & (df.month == 1)]
```

To print more rows you can change the settings by including the following line below your imports:

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = 6000
```

Comment: To be honest I do not understand how the above code works, I am currently looking my api reference, but I could use some extra help I cannot get the code to work.

Comment: One thing you will have to do is change the date from an index to a Column to make this work.

Comment: Is the filed already formatted as a datetime object?  What is the type(df.Date.values[1]) give you?  If the type is a string you will have to convert it to a datetime object first.

Comment: I took the date out of the index, but It still does not work, The max rows works

Comment: it is a string, now to convert it to datetime do I do df= datetime.datetime?

Comment: Try `df.Date = df.Date(dateutil.parser.parse)` if that doesn't work we can write a custom one.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "dframt1est.py", line 8, in <module>
     df.Date = df.Date(dateutil.parser.parse)
    NameError: name 'dateutil' is not defined
    Press any key to continue . . .
I get this error message

Comment: did you import it first as I showed above?  `import dateutil.parser`

Comment: df.Date = df.Date(dateutil.parser.parse)
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

Comment: Ok it works, but when I print( df ["dow'] ) I get the number of the day which is good, but how do I get it to where is only gives my all the Fridays or all the Januaries from 1990 to current date?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isoweekday' I get an error I can't believe how hard this is

Comment: See update.  I've added the helper function for month which you clearly didn't put in your solution.

Comment: It isn't really hard.  You didn't provide any example data so I'm just giving you syntax without checking it myself :/.

Comment: The example date is listed above under my code,  and I still have an error   df["month"] = df.Date.apply(month)
NameError: name 'month' is not defined

Comment: I can't copy and paste text into a data frame.  Unless you give me the .csv or tell me how to dl it from the internet using the stock api I don't have any data.

Comment: Did you add the function for month before calling that function?!?

Comment: Yes I added it? I got the data from yahoo finance ticker symbol CDE